# ¿Cómo le hago para crear arrays individuales apartir de un array principal que contiene otros?

Tags: php

```
Array
   (
     [0]=>Array
        (
          [0]=>10
          [1]=>11
          [2]=>12
          [3]=>13
          [4]=>14
        )
     [1]=>Array
        (
          [0]=>19
          [1]=>21
          [2]=>23
          [3]=>26
          [4]=>28
        )
      [2]=>Array
         (
           [0]=>64
           [1]=>67
           [2]=>70
           [3]=>72
           [4]=>73
         )
  )
```

Lo que pasa es que quiero realizar una búsqueda en otro array, y quiero que por cada índice del array principal me realice la búsqueda, y al final me devuelva la cantidad de cada elemento encontrado.
Supongamos que en el array que debo realizar la búsqueda tengo los siguientes elementos:

```
a=array{11,13,21,26,28,70,73}.
```

Lo que debería mostrarme al final es:

```
c=array{[0]=>2,[1]=>3,[2]=>2}
```

Comment: agrega una etiqueta con el lenguaje de programacion que estas usando. Intenta agregar toda la informacion que puedas tal como esta tu pregunta es dificil contestarte

Comment: El lenguaje es php.

Comment: ¿Qué has investigado/intentado? ¿Qué problemas o errores tienes o qué no entiendes de lo investigado? ¿Qué código has al menos balbuceado para resolver este problema? ¿Qué esperas obtener y qué obtienes? Pulsa en [edit] y completa la pregunta.

Comment: Explica mejor tu problema.. no entiendo como de un arreglo, y de otro arreglo, llegas a esa solucion. Ademas, agrega lo que intentaste...